# Hadoop Pig Latin always fails to Load Data

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm making my first steps in Hadoop's Pig Latin,but I'm really blocked since i can't load any input data even if it exists

```
R = LOAD '/home/cloudera/Desktop/vol.csv' USING PigStorage(';')  
AS 
(AnneeVol:int,MoisVol:int,JourVol:int,NumVol:int,AeroDep:chararray,AeroArriv:chararray,DistVol:int);
```

File Location

[image]

upon running :

```
DUMP R;
```

I get this error

```
> Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1590934825774_0010  R   MAP_ONLY    Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/home/cloudera/pig_lab/input/vol.csv
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1304)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:270)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/home/cloudera/pig_lab/input/vol.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:274)
    ... 18 more
    hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/temp14790577/tmp132115611,


Input(s): Failed to read data from "/home/cloudera/pig_lab/input/vol.csv"

Output(s): Failed to produce result in "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/temp14790577/tmp132115611"
```

How do I fix this issue ? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program try to find the `vol.csv` in the HDFS not on your local file system

`Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/home/cloudera/pig_lab/input/vol.csv`

Please check `core-site.xml` for your default fileSystem. Currently it would have value `hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020`. Thats why it searches the file HDFS. You DON'T have to change anything there.

Just add `file://` tag before the path to tell the program to find the `vol.csv` from your local fileSystem.

```
R = LOAD 'file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/vol.csv' USING PigStorage(';')  AS (AnneeVol:int,MoisVol:int,JourVol:int,NumVol:int,AeroDep:chararray,AeroArriv:chararray,DistVol:int);
```

Ref: [Cloudera blog](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/PIG-Store-Command-not-working-in-local-mode/td-p/113250)

---

If that doesn’t help either put the file in HDFS and then refer that location in your code.

```sh
hdfs dfs -put /home/cloudera/Desktop/vol.csv hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/<hdfs-user>/
```

Then in your code

```
R = LOAD '/user/<hdfs-user>/vol.csv' USING PigStorage(';')  AS (AnneeVol:int,MoisVol:int,JourVol:int,NumVol:int,AeroDep:chararray,AeroArriv:chararray,DistVol:int);
```

Comment: But I still wonder why the 1st one doesn’t. In which node your application master getting created? Is it one the same node where your `vol.csv` exists?

Comment: did some reaserch,it was because i was using grunt